# Bootstrap - Input-group-btn doesn't clip to input-group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying to implement it in my web app.
I want to group three different parts so that its looking nice, but the result of the code below makes the `<button>` float to the right side of the browser.

I think this means the grouping works, since its on the same row. But somehow the `<button>` still doesn't clip to the `<input/>`. I've used [This bootstrap components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) page as a reference/example to make generate my code.

**My question:** How do I make the `<button>` "clip/snap" onto the `<input/>` ?

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
    Add project:
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Type new project here"/>
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Add</button>
</div>
```

This is what my result looks like (*Note: contains different text, but the code is the same*):

[image: Result of my code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class `pull-left`, this will clip it to the `<input/>`.
See updated code below:

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
    Add project:
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-group" placeholder="Type new project here"/>
<div class="input-group-btn pull-left"> <!-- add pull-left here -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Add</button>
</div>
```