# bootstrap input group not grouping with each other

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap input group for my bootstrap-datepicker. The problem is the placement of the input and the `input-group-addon`. they are not grouping with each other.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkMe" onclick="disableMyText()">Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine, as you can see from the snippet I edited in to your question. You must have some other CSS rules in your page which are interfering with bootstrap. Use the DOM inspector to diagnose them.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for responding. I don't have any other CSS that can interfere with bootstrap.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help then, as you can see from the snippet above, what you have works fine in isolation.

Comment: Use the `pull-left`-class at the input-group-addon div.
For some reason it behaves like this, maybe only at bigger screen sizes?[Possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40019144/6501094)